# How to receive Date field from json service

Tags: angular

I have a class Person with a date field in it:

```
export class Persoon {
   name: string;
   dateOfBirth: Date;
}
```

My Java server gives a json string like:

```
{"person":{"name":"Jansen","dateOfBirth":"1959-04-16"}}
```

In the debugger I get the impression that AngularJS2 thinks it's a string, when I use a datepipe the following error occurs:

EXCEPTION: Invalid argument '1959-04-16' for pipe 'DatePipe' in [{{person.dateOfBirth | date:"dd-MM-yy"}} in PersonenComponent@26:10]

How can I make a Date of dateOfBirth?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to map the string field to a date one:

```
getList() : Observable<SomeModel[]> {
  return this._http.get(this._getListUrl).map(data => {
    return this.extractData(data);
  });
}

// parse a date in yyyy-mm-dd format
function parseDate(input) {
  var parts = input.split('-');
  return new Date(parts[0], parts[1]-1, parts[2]); // Note: months are 0-based
}

private extractData(res: Response) {
  var data = res.json().data || [];
  data.forEach((d) => {
    d.dateOfBirth = this.parseDate(d.dateOfBirth);
  });
  return data;
}
```

See this question:

- [Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

Comment: Why do I get an error on this line: var data = res.json().data || []; when I try to use this code? "Property data does not exist on type Promise<any>"